# extract day number of year from dates

Tags: r, date

I have a list of dates like these:

```
library(lubridate)
my.dates <- c("03-01-2006", "28-01-2006", "12-01-2008", "02-02-2006", "03-03-2008")
my.dates <- dmy(my.dates)
```

I need to extract, the day number of the year from each date as below, where 1st January is day 1:

```
day.number <- c(3, 28, 12, 33, 62)
```

I've had a good hunt around google and SO but cannot find an easy way of doing this. Help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: @DidzisElferts That is *not* a duplicate - the key issue here is the **lubridate** representation of the dates, which is significantly different from the `POSIXt`-based solutions in the duplicate you propose. I have voted to leave open in the review queue.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you can use `yday` function from `lubridate` since you're already using it:

```
> yday(my.dates)
# [1]  3 28 12 33 63
```

Comment: Thanks. Apologies for missing question already asked. I'm using `lubridate` so will stick with that package

Answer (score 19):

Try `POSIXlt` and its `attributes(my.dates)`

```
my.dates = as.POSIXlt(my.dates,format="%d-%m-%Y")
my.dates$mday
[1]  3 28 12  2  3
my.dates$yday
[1]  2 27 11 32 62
```

Comment: Notice that the yday values are 0-based.